# unix command to truncate file contents

Tags: unix, cygwin

can someone help me with unix command to truncate the contents of the files in the directory. I am using Cygwin in windows.

Comment: not sure what you are asking here....can you clarify the question

Comment: suppose there is directory (xyz) containing 10 files which have some content. now i want to remove there content not the files itself. So that the empty files with same name exists for further use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for file in *
do
  >$file
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Just redirect from nowhere:

```
> somefile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, wow, that works i am curious to know how/why ? redirection from nothing to the file makes content empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truncate a file to keep the n last lines of a file, you can do something like (500 lines in this example)

```
mv file file.tmp && tail -n 500 file.tmp > file && rm file.tmp
```